# Getting Pango-WARNING: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()

Tags: linux, centos, exim, munin

About three days ago, I noticed the exim mailqueue started filling up on one of my servers, and upon inspecting some of the emails using `# exim -Mvb $ID`, I noticed they were being sent to some system email address (which is not a real address), and the body of the messages were as follows:

```
(process:8259): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()
```

I'm wondering what could be causing this strange issue, as I've never heard of 'pango' at all... I've never seen that function used in my lifetime!

It seems the process id (PID) is for an apache process, though, as the pids are always gone by the time I use `# ps -aux` to look them up.

Edit: Whoops! Forgot to include the subject - looks like it's actually munin-cron that's bringing up the issue:

```
Subject: Cron  /usr/bin/munin-cron --force-root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... looks like it was a bug in munin causing this issue. Since the server in question uses cPanel/WHM, and munin was installed through there, I can't easily upgrade munin. Grrr...

http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=20468

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug found on one of the munin plugins. Found some different character before the degrees bit.

```
/etc/munin/plugins/hddtemp_smartctl
```

changed

```
"graph_vlabel temp in °C\n";
```

to

```
"graph_vlabel temp in C\n";
```